# How to play Vimeo videos in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, vimeo

I create an iOS app that make use of Vimeo for playing videos. I was wondering what the best method is to show Vimeo videos within iOS Swift.

I have fixed that, when an image is clicked, the placeholder image will be hidden, but the video won't play directly. Beside that all Vimeo Interface elements are visible. I know you should have to give credits to Vimeo, so it goes without saying that I display an Vimeo logo at the bottom of the video. Is there a possibility to hide all Vimeo elements of the web player?

Sources where I can find more information would be nice.
If there are any questions left, let me know! 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you considered or are you using [a SDK to play Vimeo videos](https://github.com/vimeo/VIMNetworking)?  or are you simply using an API to get the movie data?

Comment: See -> https://github.com/satishVekariya/LXVimeoKit

Answer (score 11):

You can use this Swift library [HCVimeoVideoExtractor](https://github.com/superm0/HCVimeoVideoExtractor) to extract the mp4 video URL then use AVPlayer to play it. Simply pass the Vimeo video link or video id.

```
let url = URL(string: "https://vimeo.com/254597739")!
HCVimeoVideoExtractor.fetchVideoURLFrom(url: url, completion: { ( video:HCVimeoVideo?, error:Error?) -> Void in                
    if let err = error {                    
       print("Error = \(err.localizedDescription)")                    
       return
    }

    guard let vid = video else {
        print("Invalid video object")
        return
    }

    print("Title = \(vid.title), url = \(vid.videoURL), thumbnail = \(vid.thumbnailURL)")

    if let videoURL = vid.videoURL[.Quality540p] {
        let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)
        let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
        playerController.player = player
        self.present(playerController, animated: true) {
            player.play()
        }
    }                            
})
```

Comment: This library simply parses the JSON returned by `https://player.vimeo.com/video/[video ID]/config`.

Answer (score 8):

The best way that I've been able to figure out is to use a `WKWebView` or `UIWebView`. Steps:

1. Add a `WKWebView` of desired size inside the View Controller.
2. Get the video embed code from the original Vimeo video (Click on the "Share" button below the video to find the embed code.)

   [image]
3. Click on "More Options" on the Vimeo Share sheet that pops-up to configure the look of the embed video.
4. Use the following code sample to embed the video:

   ```
   let webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height))
   self.view.addSubview(webView)

   let embedHTML="<html><head><style type=\"text/css\">body {background-color: transparent;color: black;}</style><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes\"/></head><body style=\"margin:0\"><div><iframe src=\"//player.vimeo.com/video/139785390?autoplay=1&amp;title=1&amp;byline=1&amp;portrait=0\" width=\"640\" height=\"360\" frameborder=\"0\" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe></div></body></html>"
   let url = URL(string: "https://")!
   webView.loadHTMLString(embedHTML as String, baseURL:url )
   webView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
   ```

Comment: Hello Nitin, Can you please tell me your vimeo account type from which you have hosted this video as Title share button etc are not showing on it?

Comment: I just checked the vimeo embed link and the code hasn't changed since 2016. I didn't exactly get your question? I don't have access to the account I was working with then, but it was a Vimeo Pro user account. In vimeo, I think the video uploader can chose to make the video un-embedable, if that's what you're stuck with.

Answer (score 3):

For **Swift 4**, I have used **WKWebView** in storyboard and implemented following code:

```
import WebKit
```

@IBOutlet weak var webKitView: WKWebView!

To play video in WebView :

```
if yourVimeoLink.lowercased().contains("vimeo.com") {
            let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: yourVimeoLink)
            webKitView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
            webKitView.load(URLRequest(url: url as URL))
```

}

Hope will help! :)

Answer (score 2):

The way that I've managed to implement this is using `AVKit` and `AVFoundation`:

```
let url: URL! = URL(string: "https://01-lvl3-pdl.vimeocdn.com/01/3355/3/91775232/243724947.mp4?expires=1498547278&token=073f7b03877a8ed3c8029")
let player: AVPlayer = AVPlayer(url: url)
let controller: AVPlayerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()

controller.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
controller.player = player

// Add `controller` to your view somehow

player.play()
```

The trick being that you cannot use the link where it displays the website (in my case https://vimeo.com/91775232).

I had to inspect the source and find the actual URL for the video (i.e.: https://01-lvl3-pdl.vimeocdn.com/01/3355/3/91775232/243724947.mp4?expires=1498547278&token=073f7b03877a8ed3c8029).

Once I used that, everything worked fine.

Comment: Hey where I get source link of video in Vimeo ?

Comment: This won't work - the vimeocdn URL can't be used directly: the full URL you posted here has an "expires" attribute, and will give a `403 Forbidden` error after it expires.

Answer (score -4):

```
import AVFoundation
import AVKit

let videoURL = "https://vimeo.com/blablabla/whatevertheURLis"

func playExternalVideo() {
    let videoURL = NSURL(string: self.videoURL)
    let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL as! URL)
    let playerViewController = AVPlayerView()

    playerViewController.player = player
}
```

Make sure to add the AVKit Player View and give it a class of AVPlayerView. As for the Vimeo deal, it should play without Vimeo's UI Controls. For more help watch this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fhD7hXrpExE

Comment: These are general instructions to play a video file using AVPlayer. This won't work for web-streaming Vimeo videos.

Comment: I'm almost certain Apple takes care of the streaming but by all means correct me if I'm wrong. @Nitin

Comment: Yes Apple's AV player libraries can stream content. But if I remember right Vimeo presents additional restrictions. Have you specifically tried playing a Vimeo video using this method?

Comment: You might just be correct. I haven't tried using Vimeo yet. I'll need to do a little research on that. @Nitin